# npm package.json install globally?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there any way to set an NPM dependency to be installed globally in the package.json file?

Whenever I run `npm update` all the dependencies are installed locally.

Thanks.

Comment: Although it's best to install libraries locally if you have multiple projects in parallel due to speed at which new versions come out. It's annoying to break one of your other projects because you globally installed a newer version.

Comment: @Raynos yeah that's what i'm doing for most of the packages. There are some that are useful only in global though

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the `-g` option causes things to be installed globally.

Comment: isn't that only in the command line? where do i put it in the json

Comment: It seems that it installs current project globally not its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Is your reason for installing globally in order to make new scripts available on the command line?  If so, I might have a workaround for you.

Just install your packages as usual (without the `-g`):

```
npm install -S my_module_name
```

Including the `-S` flag or `--save` will help keep your `package.json` file up to date.

As usual, your project's `npm install` step will install locally (as you have described).  However, it will also produces a local folder containing symlinks to each of the project's npm-supplied command-line executables (located inside the `node_modules/.bin/` folder).

Add that folder to your system path to enable command-line access to `npm` modules without requiring installation via `-g`, or root access to a machine:

```
export PATH=/path/to/your/project/source/node_modules/.bin/:$PATH
```